# How do you send a user to your app's settings from iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there a way to launch the iPhone/iPad's settings from within your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://bitbucket.org/karemorstol/mysettings/wiki/Installation) out:  It is a framework to display the apps's settings in both places, or just just on the app using the same type of display as the settings pane.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. What apps usually do is recreate the same view the user would see if they opened the settings and then display that in-app.